# Python "if" statement - if xpath is true

Tags: python, xpath

im trying to code in python (very new to it) and need to check if an xpath is there then variable = the xpath but if not variable = string.

An example is below

```
if tree.xpath('//*@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/span/text()') = true

$value = tree.xpath('//*@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/span/text()')

else

$value = ''
```

Comment: Please read python docs first

Comment: Any non empty list will be considered truthy,  check if the xpath is not empty and if not set your variable equal to the content

Comment: please fix your code's indentation.

Comment: This is not Python, it's an awful mix of Python and PHP and maybe C++ and Pascal. `if` and `else` must have a `:` after the condition. `True` is written with a capital 'T', not like in C++. Comparison is `==`, not `=` like in Pascal. Variables don't normally begin with `$` like they do in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really start by doing the *whole* official tutorial before anything else, as it will anwser your question.

First point : Python objects all have a 'truth' value in a boolean context, which is defined by the object's type and actual value. For builtin types, all empty containers (lists, dicts, sets etc), the empty string, all numerical zeros and the `None` object are false, everything else is true. For non builtin types you'll have to check the package's documentation.

The builtin type `bool` will also tell you the boolean value of a given object, so all of the below tests are equivalent:

```
if myobj: 
    xxx

if bool(myobj):
   xxx

if bool(myobj) == True:
   xxx
```

BUT keep in mind that it doesn't imply that `bool(myobj)` is the same as `myobj` - the first one is the boolean value of your object, so the following is NOT equivalent (unless `myobj` is one of `True`, `1` or `1.0`):

```
if myobj == True:
    xxx
```

Now wrt/ your actual code snippet: it's not valid Python (bad indentation, invalid identifier `$value`, invalid use of the assignment operator `=`, missing `:` after the `if` and `else` statements, wrong capitalization for `True`...)

Assuming you meant:

```
# let's make this at least readable:
path = '//*@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/span/text()'
if tree.xpath(path) == True:
    value = tree.xpath(path)
else:
    value = ''
```

The obvious error is the explicit test against `True` (tree.xpath() doesn't return a boolean). You either have to explicitely cast the return of `tree.xpath()` to a boolean (which is quite verbose, totally useless and definitly unpythonic) or just let Python do the right thing by removing the `== True` part of your test.

As a side note: calling `tree.xpath` twice in a row with the same argument is a waste of processor cycle (both calls will return the same value), so use a variable instead - it will also make your code much more readable and maintainable. The Pythonic version of your code would look something like:

```
path = '//*@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/span/text()'  
found = tree.xpath(path)
value = found if found else ''
```

or even more simply:

```
path = '//*@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/span/text()'  
value = tree.xpath(path) or ''
```

since the `or` operator will not yield a boolean value but either the first of it's operand that has a true value or the last operand if none has a true value.

Comment: This makes sence - sorry i come from a php background that's why you saw a lot of php in the code.

When i run the bottom code i get an error lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression on found = tree.xpath(path)

Comment: @emmaperkins this is another - mostly unrelated - question. And how to deal with exceptions is ALSO documented (in the official tutorial and doc).

Comment: Thanks this is a brilliant answer and helped me alot

Comment: @emmaperkins this `//*@id="page"]` is invalid XPath expression, it should've been `//*[@id="page"]` which reads *find elements of any name, anywhere in the XML/HTML document, where `id` attribute value equals `"page"`*

Answer (score 0):

```
#No need to test == if value is bool. and you not check, you assign value with one =
if anything:
   #Then do this
else:
   #Do this
```